# Show "Viewed by" in the mod tools only if it was viewed after the post was flagged

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flags

Currently it shows if a moderator viewed the post even if said moderator viewed it sometime in the past, which isn't useful for knowing at a glance if a fellow mod evaluated the flag, in order to tend to the new ones first.

Comment: I've never been sure if it did this or not. I guess it doesn't

Comment: I thought it already did this. I'm pretty sure I've viewed a question before it was flagged and then didn't see myself in the list of mods who viewed the flagged question. But now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @BenBrocka, wasn't sure either, until I say a new flag with a mod in the viewed by section, and that mod hadn't been active recently. I don't trust the "activity" neither but worst case scenario this post gets closed.